# JNI unsatisfiedlinkerror after client installation

Tags: java, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I had to make a C++ bridge between java application and .NET dll, that's why I used JNI.

On my environment all works fine, but when tried to another non-developer computer I catch `unsatisfiedlinkerror exception`.

My question is: is it necessary to have JDK for using jni or is it possible with jre which doesn't have include directory where are jni common files?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It rather seems like your JNI library is not visible. Make sure to put it on PATH or add it to java.library.path.

If you can provide stack trace, this would definitely help to check whether this is related to your JNI library or some other library that is used by your code.